# onActivityResult not working with android:launchMode="singleTask"

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, onactivityresult

I call Activity-B from Activity-A where there is need for **android:launchMode="singleTask"** in Activity-B and **onActivityResult** in Activity-A.

I am facing a problem with **onActivityResult** in Activity-A when Activity-B is finished **onActivityResult** in Activity-A not execute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since  Activity-B is a **singleTask** I am afraid that you can not return a resulft from it, as the documentations state:

> For example, if the activity you are launching uses the singleTask launch mode,
>   it will not run in your task and thus you will immediately receive a cancel result.

So you can not return a result from it, and there is no way to get around it if you need Activity-B to be singleTask.

Since you have developed Activity-B by yourself you can make some little changes and have it to send a **broadcast** with the result and Activity-A can then list to this broadcast and get the result.

Comment: I was think about this solution.

Comment: I guess it is the right way to go, mark this as answer please so if somebody else gets this problem it can see it :) Good Luck!

Comment: What android version this affects ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent%2C%20int%2C%20android.os.Bundle)) for `onActivityResult()`:

> " [...] For example, if the activity you are launching uses the singleTask launch mode, it will not run in your task and thus you will immediately receive a cancel result."

Comment: is there any another way to do this ?